# How to display selected value from selectBox?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to show data, but it shows the number value of selected item, how can i fix that and show the value of selected item

[image]

TS code:

```
 listObjectif: any[]=[];
  selectedObjectif1: string[] = []; 

Selectobjectif() {
    this.ObjectifService.findAll().then((res)=>{
      this.listObjectif = res.map(function (obj:any) {
        return {
          value: obj.id,
          label: obj.libelle
        };
      });
    });
  }
```

My HTML:

```
 <p-multiSelect [options]="listObjectif" [(ngModel)]="selectedObjectif1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                         [selectionLimit]=3 [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" [maxSelectedLabels]=5></p-multiSelect>
          <p>Selected Cities: {{selectedObjectif1}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the component.html file, modify the `p-multiselect` definition in the following way,

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="listObjectif" [(ngModel)]="selectedObjectif1" optionLabel="label" optionValue="label" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [selectionLimit]=3 [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" [maxSelectedLabels]=5></p-multiSelect>

<p>{{selectedObjectif1 | json}}</p>
```

The option itself is bound to the model by default, therefore we use `optionValue` to customize the property to pass as the value instead.

For your reference please find a link to a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-nwmx9k?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Edit:** For earlier versions of PrimeNG,

You would need to modify the object passed in the `options` attribute, such that the `value` property of the object is an object itself containing `id` and `name` properties.

In the component.ts file, modify the `selectObjectIf()` method in the following way,

```js
this.ObjectifService.findAll().then((res) => {
  this.listObjectif = res.map(function(obj: any) {
    return {
      value: {
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.libelle
      },
      label: obj.libelle
    };
  });
});
}
```

So that the resulting `listObjectif` appears to be,

```js
[{
    label: "",
    value: {
      id: ,
      name: ""
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Such that properties `label` and `value.name` are equal.

Then in your component.html file, modify the definition of `p-multiSelect` in the following way,

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="listObjectif" [(ngModel)]="selectedObjectif1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [selectionLimit]=3 [panelStyle]="{minWidth:'12em'}" [maxSelectedLabels]=5 optionLabel="label"></p-multiSelect>

<ng-container *ngFor="let object of selectedObjectif1">
  <p>{{object.value.name}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: it says Attribute optionValue is not allowed here, I am using primeng 8 + angular 8

Comment: Unresolved variable value in the html file. can't read value in<p>{{object.value.name}}</p>" !!

Comment: You are adding `optionLabel="label"` in the `p-multiSelect` definition, right? Also for your reference adding link to a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-mulstiselect-fsen4b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: what if I want to display the data in chips! like that **<p-chips [(ngModel)]=" object.value.libelle" ></p-chips>**  how to edit it please!

Comment: For that, you could push the selected `object.value.libelle` to an array referenced by `p-chips` on the `onChange` event of the `p-multiselect`. And similarly pop the unselected values. Also, I would be highly obliged if you could upvote/approve my answer if it helped you resolve your issue. Thank you.

Comment: for this {{object.value.name}} !! value still show me an error "Unresolved variable value "

Comment: You have to loop through the `selectedObjectif1` using `*ngFor` as shown in the answer. Also, could you please ensure that the `listObjectif` object has `value` property as an object containing `name` `id` as its properties?

Comment: here is it the structure of object I get from the function {id: 1, libelle: "test", id_examen: null}

Comment: Well you need to modify your function such that, it modifies the structure of the object like [{ libelle: "test", value: { id: 1, name: "test"}, id_examen: null }]

Comment: Thank u so much for ur help in the precedent  question, I aprroved it, I would appreciate it more if u help me to fix the chips in stackblitz. I am stucking there :/